# Create array using _.each

Tags: javascript, arrays, functional-programming, underscore.js, each

I've this exercise to solve:

> Use _.each to create an array from 1, 1000 (inclusive)

I really don't know how to do that and i'm thinking it's not possible...

Can you help me?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9wyef08h/1/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `functional-programming` tag on the question is the clue. :-) In functional programming, usually loops are written as recursion. So how can we use recursion to build an array using `_.each`? By making the callback call it:

```js
var array = _.each([1], function cb(e, i, a) {
  if (a.length < 1000) {
    a.push(a.length + 1);
    _.each(a, cb);
  }
});
snippet.log(array.length);
snippet.log(array.join(", "));
```

```html
<script src="http://underscorejs.org/underscore-min.js"></script>
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Or being **really** naughty, we could start with a 1000-character string:

```js
var oneThousand = 
    "01234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789" +
    "01234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789" +
    "01234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789" +
    "01234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789" +
    "01234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789" +
    "01234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789" +
    "01234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789" +
    "01234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789" +
    "01234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789" +
    "01234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789" +
    "01234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789" +
    "01234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789" +
    "01234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789" +
    "01234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789" +
    "01234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789" +
    "01234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789" +
    "01234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789" +
    "01234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789" +
    "01234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789" +
    "01234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789";
var array = [];
_.each(oneThousand, function(e, i) {
  array[i] = i + 1;
});
snippet.log(array.length);
snippet.log(array.join(", "));
```

```html
<script src="http://underscorejs.org/underscore-min.js"></script>
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

...but I'm sure that's cheating.

Comment: You blew my mind with this code! I know it's a basic problem but to use recursion had not crossed my mind, so thank you for that suggestion!

Answer (score 3):

You can create an empty array of 1000 elements by passing the required array length to [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) constructor, then use `_.each()` to assign value to each of the index in the array.

```js
var array = _.each(new Array(1000), function(v, i, a) {
  a[i] = i + 1;
});
console.log(array)
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Oh, it was so easy that i can't see it :S thank you!

Comment: This will depend a **lot** on the interpretation of the assignment. :-)